# How to get value of elements with same id using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to show the value of the first input box when I click on first delete link and show the value of the second input box when I click on the second delete link by with using the same id but it is always sending the first delete link's value.

```js
function delChat() {
   var id = document.getElementById('delmsg').value;
   alert(id);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="delChat()">Delete?</a>
<input type="hidden" value="1352" id="delmsg" >
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="delChat()">Delete?</a>
<input type="hidden" value="1350" id="delmsg" >
```

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: use class for more than one element. ID IS UNIQUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use same id's for two different elements. Every element on a page should have unique id.

But if you can not change the id, then you should get the attribute this way:

```js
function delChat(el) {
   console.log(el.getAttribute('value') + " clicked");
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open('GET', 'delete.php?id='+el.getAttribute('value'), true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="delmsglink" onclick="delChat(this)" value="1352">Delete?</a>
<br />
<a href="#" id="delmsglink" onclick="delChat(this)" value="1350">Delete?</a>
```

Comment: I can't change the id... because it is printed in a loop

Comment: i want to get the value of link clicked and then send it to php so it can delete the row where id is equals to the value of link

Comment: @Dev.Joel You are right but according to OP, he can not change the id. I have already mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

could stop using id for these cases, it would be enough just to pass the element that was clicked as a parameter for the function both in the html with the reserved word this and in the js, to get the value attribute you can use [getAttribute ('value')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
function delChat(el) {
  let id = el.getAttribute('value');
  console.log(id);
  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="delChat(this)" value="1352">Delete?</a>
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="delChat(this)" value="1350">Delete?</a>
```

to have a more manageable code, it would be ideal to add the function from JS and not use in the HTML, but it would be necessary to add a class to reference them *(linkdel)*

```js
function delChat() {
  let id = this.getAttribute('value');
  console.log(id);
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('.linkdel');
links.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click',delChat,false);
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="linkdel" value="1352">Delete?</a>
<br />
<a href="#" class="linkdel" value="1350">Delete?</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`id`s have to be unique. The best alternative is to use a class and attach event listeners to each element. You can use `this` in the function called by the event listener to point to the element that was clicked. Also `value` isn't a valid attribute of `a` so use a data attribute instead: `data-value` - the values of data attributes can be accessed through the element's `dataset` object.

```js
function delChat() {
  var id = this.dataset.value;
  console.log(id);
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.del');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', delChat, false));
```

```html
<a href="#" class="del" data-value="1352">Delete?</a>
<br />
<a href="#" class="del" data-value="1350">Delete?</a>
```